# Extended Kalman Filter Covariance Converges too Fast

Tags: kalman-filter

I'm teaching myself how to use extended kalman filters and have written a filter where both the error and covariance are converging. However, the covariance drops to nearly its convergent value immediately.

During the first iteration, at the covariance update step ( P = (I-KH)Pminus), some of the diagonals of KH become 1. This causes the corresponding diagonals of the new covariance P to be nearly zero.

Is this a "normal" occurrence with EK filters or a bug?

I've tried increasing the covariance noise but this doesn't seem to have much of an impact. Additionally, I've been going over my H matrix but cannot find any errors. Am I right to assume that K is less likely to have an error, since both the state estimate and covariance converge?

Comment: You should set your initial covariance to some really large value. Unless you have some good reason to believe your initial state estimation is somewhat accurate. You did try just bumping up that value right?

Answer (score 0):

In the Kalman fit, the measurements make the entries of the state covariance shrink via the intermediate of the Kalman gain in the update step, and the prediction step makes your state covariance entries grow via the process noise term.

If your fit is implemented correctly, and the entries of KH become close to one, then this means that the entries of the measurement covariance matrix are really small compared to the entries of the state covariance (where the comparison of relative sizes has to take into account whatever happens in you H, say, a change of units from parsec to millimeter).

The easiest way to check your implementation is to implement a measurement where one of your state variables is measured directly, i.e. H is of the form `H = { 0, ..., 0, 1, 0, 0, ... }`.  If you now put the same value in both the corresponding diagonal entry of the covariance matrix, keeping it diagonal to avoid complications from covariances, and in your (1D) measurement covariance, then the updated state should fall right in the middle of the state before the update (i.e. the predicted state) and the measured value, and the covariance entry should shrink in half.